# How to create an app bundle with an exe and a directory hierarchy?

Tags: xcode, bundle, xcode9, macos-mojave, xcode10.1

I am struggling to create macOS application bundle that follows [this hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW19).

I am currently on XCode 10.1 and I also have XCode 9.0.

However, I just cant find a way to get the folder hierarchy as mentioned in the above link.

Specifically, I want to have the localization `.lproj` directories in `Contents/Resources` and app exe in `Contents/MacOS`.

I do `File-->New-->Project` but I just cant seem to find an option which will produce this hierarchy.

Am I

- missing something obvious here ?
- using a wrong version of XCode ?

TIA

Comment: Xcode -> File -> New -> Project -> macOS -> App

Comment: @rmaddy Yup, thats something I have already tried. It creates an app but does not have the directory structure as mentioned in the question. Also , in Xcode 9/10, there is no "App", its "Cocoa App".

Comment: Yes, it does have that structure. It's all inside the resulting .app that is generated when you build the project.